# How to make radio boxes in XAML (Xamarin Forms PCL)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, radio-button

I am trying to find out how to make a radio button in XAML - I see there is a way to do it in android but was wondering if there is a simple cross platform way to do it without needing additional nuget packages.

Comment: Just make it with 2 images, one command and 2 gesture recognizers,  and one property, that bind with IsVisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to my findings, there is no any in-built Radio button in Xamarin.

Directly to your answer @Sparkz, there is method to build custom Radio button, but it is using other nuget packages to implement it.

I also had the same problem, but I used xamarin Picker in my project instead Radio button. You can download sample of Picker from this link:-

[Xamarin.Picker](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/PickerDemo/)

Comment: That is a great solution if you are not required to adopt voiceover or accessibility features. in this case, the picker is so impossible to make it readable and then you will have to be back to the original question. how to add radio buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Refer This Link https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML it will help you

Comment: Thank you for your reply, looking at the link you sent it appears to use xlabs which I have read is great and all but I was really wanting to avoid using addons for a simple form element which literally be used once. - do you know of any alternative methods?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I have found for the moment by the controls of xamarin.forms, I hope it helps.

[XFControls](https://github.com/gruan01/XFControls)

Here nugets [XFControls nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XFCustomControls)

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a `BindableRadioButton` http://puresourcecode.com/page/psc-xamarin-controls-bindableradiobutton-component for all platforms (iOS, Android and UWP).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a nuget for ios, only android.